# Dynamic programming: find the maximum revenue

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is the weighted job scheduling problem in `O(N log N)` using dynamic programming

```
How each list is structured = [city, start_day, end_day, revenue]
rev = [['A', 1, 7, 5], ['B', 6, 9, 4], ['C', 1, 5, 3]]
>>> print(max_rev(rec))
['B', 6, 9, 4], ['C', 1, 5, 3]
```

My attempt for n log n:

1. Sort the list based on the last day in a city using a modified merge sort **(n log n)**, this will get me `[['C', 1, 5, 3], ['A', 1, 7, 5], ['B', 6, 9, 4]]` number them 0 -> n according to its index now (I mentioned insertion sort before, I messed up as its worst case is n^2, hence I'm using merge sort now)
2. ***clueless from here**. Create a `memo list of n (3) size` and each index of `memo` represents the index position of a particular city in now sorted rev
3. Each index of the memo will contain the maximum revenue the salesman can obtain if he works at that city. Do this by looping through the sorted list, and for each city information, add up all the revenues between it and the cities that has a greater start_day then the selected city's end_day.

Comment: The revenue you’ve mentioned in the example is on a per day basis? Or it’s the amount he gets for selling for the entire duration?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Hey, sorry for that. It's the entire duration

Comment: What reason(s) do you have to suspect that this problem is solvable in better than quadratic time? You'd need to know which pairs of intervals conflict with each other. There can be `O(n^2)` such pairs, so it's not immediately clear how to you could do this is better than quadratic time.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark because of dynamic programming and backtracking. I found this question listed under the particular topic

Comment: Dynamic programming algorithms aren't all `O(n log n)` or `O(n)`. I thought you could potentially make this faster by using graph modeling (creating a DAG and then doing longest path in a DAG), but this graph would have a quadratic number of edges. That's when I realized that this might not be possible to do in faster than quadratic time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a good start.  Let's begin with your sorted and numbered list of jobs.

Consider the question: "how much money can you make if you can only work jobs with numbers <= i".  Call this `money(i)`. `money(n-1)` is the answer you're looking for.

Obviously `money(0)` is the value of job 0.

`money(i)` for the following jobs can be easily calculated if you know the results for the previous jobs:

```c
money(i) = max(
    money(i-1),  // this is the value if we don't do job i
    job_value(i), // this is the case when we only do job i
    job_value(i) + money(j) // j is the highest value job that ends before i starts
)
```

Now you just have to find the best `j`.  The part you missed is that `money(i)` is *always* at least as big as `money(i-1)` -- it never hurts to have another job available, so the best job `j` is always the *highest numbered* job that ends before `i` starts.

Since your list of jobs is sorted by end time, you can find this job `j` with a binary search in O(log N) time, for O(N log N) all together.

Comment: this seems like the correct idea. Thank you! I'll be attempting to implement this in code now

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare plans, not just individual cities. The important revenue is the one of the plan although the individual cities can inform our decisions.

You example allows for 2 plans: A(5) & CB(7).

In a more complex case, you could have a tree of possibilities:

```
start ---> A(5)
       |
       |-> B ---> C(6)
       |      |
       |      \-> D(4)
       |-> C(3)
       \-> D(1)
```

I'd use backtracking to find the best solution.

In this simple example, it seems that [alpha-beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning) pruning would also immediately reduce the search space.

If you could calculate a maximum revenue per day, you could prune more aggressively.

Comment: Thanks, backtracking is definitely needed hence why I have created the memo list. However, I'm a bit clueless on how the codes would look like for this. I'm thinking binary search would be a good idea as its complexity is log N, but I don't really got a clue of what to put as what the search is searching for

Comment: @Mateybro it is searching for the path to a leaf with highest aggregate revenue.